# What is the expertise level of SharePoint Overflow (or is this site appropriate to use in beginner tutorials?)

Tags: discussion

So I'm building a tutorial for our users on SharePoint 2010, on the page "Where to go for more help." I debated putting SharePoint overflow down after a quick glance at the questions that would probably scare off a newbie asking "How to I post a document to a document library?" or similar level question. I'm just wondering, is it appropriate  nowadays to ask beginner type questions?  Or is SharePoint Overflow really an experienced people's only playground nowadays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion beginners' questions are welcome as long as they are specific and answerable as described in the FAQ and not just RTFM questions. We expect the questioner to have made some effort to find the answer first, so posting a question on SharePoint.StackExchange.com should not be the act of first resort.

What we definitely don't want is very vague and general questions like "What is SharePoint" or the like. I think the example "How do I post a document to a document library" falls into the RTFM category and that would probably form the majority of the answers.

By all means direct people to this site - the more people using it the better. Most people will learn quickly what works as a question.

Comment: Fair enough, then be prepared to Chivalrously handle a few more dupes and newb questions...

Comment: That's fine. We were all new to this at some time or other.